# How do I edit the expiration time of confirmation email in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm pretty new to ruby on rails and i want to edit the expiration time of email confirmation as 2 days. please help me for find out a solution.

Comment: expiration time of what? Please have a look at 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Devise and this is for use account creation (the question is very unclear), go to `config/initializers/devise.rb` and set it via

```
config.confirm_within = (number).days
```

It is likely commented out with the default set, so just set the number of days you want and remove the # symbol

Comment: If that file exists you are indeed using Devise and it will absolutely have worked - Devise is reliable.